# set image for UIButton

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uiimage

I want to add an image button to my xcode project. I added a Round Rect Button using the interface builder.

In my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *infobutton;
```

In my .m file:

```
@synthesize infobutton;

-viewDidLoad{
infobutton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
UIImage* infobuttonImg =[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];    
[infobutton setImage:infobuttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[infobuttonImg release];
}
```

Finally, I add a link in my interface builder linking the Round Rect Button to infobutton. However, when I run the simulator, I still got the plain Round Rect Button on my interface rather than having the button displayed as the image that I have set. I wonder if there is anything that I have missed in my code.

Comment: Expanding upon Aaron's answer, everything that's shown in your xib, other than special references like the First Responder, is loaded into memory (meaning you don't have to instantiate it) before `-viewDidLoad` is called (hence the name, view did load). Additionally, when I ran your code in XCode, nothing happened, because `[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]` was returning nil. My solution was to get an image that I embedded in the bundle (`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"get_info" ofType:@"png"]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infoButton should already be populated with a button in viewDidLoad.  In your code, you're overriding it.

Consider removing this line:

```
infobutton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
```

Also, infobuttonImg is autoreleased which means that this line is not required:

```
[infobuttonImg release];
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's right. I remove the above lines and it is working now. The image is lying on the rectangle button. Is there any way to remove the rectangle button but only have the image as a button?

Comment: You can change the button type from a rounded rectangle to a custom button, in Interface Builder.